# Is willTurnIntoFault always to be called if prepareForDeletion to be called?

Tags: ios, core-data

Now I put clean-up code both in `-willTurnIntoFault` and `-prepareForDeletion`. But it seems for every `-prepareForDeletion` call there is always a companying `-willTurnIntoFault`. So I'm wondering whether I can put clean-up code only in `-willTurnIntoFault`.

Comment: I am facing the same question currently. Did you solve it in the meantime?

Comment: No canonical answer yet.